# Add class to every other element in IE7

Tags: jquery

I need to add a class to every other `li` element. I would typically use the `nth-child(odd)` selector but I need this to work in IE7. What is the best way to add the class to every other element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('li:even').addClass('whatever');`

http://api.jquery.com/even-selector/

Comment: +1: Short and sweet. There is also an `:odd` selector too, if you need it.

Comment: @JamesJohnson true -- I wasn't thinking about it at the time, but the CSS even/odd selector is 1-based while jQuery's even/odd is zero-based, so `$('li:even')` in jQuery will match the same list elements as `li:nth-child(odd)` in CSS. http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/RFKXX/